# How can I get the current geographical location in my desktop application?

Tags: java, javafx, geolocation

I need to get when a button of GUI is clicked, the longitude and latitude of the user.

My desktop application is written in Java, my GUI in JavaFx.

I found nothing in Google Maps API

**EDIT**:

Google Maps API resolve my problem.

You can use :
[Geolocation API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geolocation/overview)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If this is a desktop application, then you only have 2 options. Either

- the desktop computer you're on has a GPS capability (e.g. a USB GPS receiver) which is highly unlikely
- or you will need to rely on the user's IP

If you want to do the latter, then in Java you can easily figure out the user's IP and then you'll need to use geo-IP services e.g. Maxmind. Have a look at their [demo here](https://www.maxmind.com/en/geoip-demo).

Comment: How localization works on the web browser e.g. with HTML5?

Comment: e.g. when I click on my position button on Google Maps, the geolocation is very accurate

Comment: They use data derived from your IP. If you are logged into chrome as well as Google maps as well as on your phone then Google can also use that information

Comment: Note that Google probably has a lot of information about all of the IPs that exist and that probably explains how well their mapping works independently of actual geodata